# linux bash dictionary check if empty

Tags: bash, shell-script, associative-array

How to check if a dictionary (associative array) is empty? I just declare one using `declare -A dict`. I want to know if it is just declared but not have any key.

Answer (score 10):

The length of (or the number of elements in) an associative array is available as `${#array[@]}`, just like for an ordinary array.  If this number is zero, then the array is empty.

```
if [ "${#array[@]}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo 'array is not empty'
fi
```

On an ordinary shell variable, may use the `-v` test to test whether it exists or not:

```
if [ -v variable ]; then
    echo 'variable exists'
fi
```

... but this does not work intuitively on arrays.  You can't therefore use this reliably to determine if an array exists but is empty, or whether it hasn't been declared yet.

The test will be true on arrays if their `0` key exists.

Comment: Hi @kusa.I find a way to check,if [[ -z ${!dict[*]} ]];this will check if any key exist.

Comment: @focuszheng This would be better: `if [ "${#dict[@]}" -ne 0 ]`.  It's better because the shell does not have to concatenate all the keys together to create a long string.

Comment: nope, if the dictionary is empty.an error "ubound variable" shows.

Comment: You can test your conditional expression on linux server and bash version >4.4.

Comment: @focuszheng You will get "unbound variable" only if you run under `set -u` (this is not the default in `bash`).  Also, it is unclear whether you want to check whether an array is empty or whether it is defined.

Comment: Hi yes.I use set -euxo in case of some exceptions.What I want to check is if the dictonary is declare(defined) but have no keys (means empty).

Comment: I just test the two condition expressions.[ "${#dict[@]}" -ne 0 ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
-su: dict: unbound variable

Comment: [ -z ${!dict[*]} ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

Answer (score 0):

With more recent versions of `bash`, the test `[[ -z ${dict[@]@K} ]]` (or `[[ ! ${dict[@]@K} ]]`) and will work even with `set -u`: the `@K` parameter transformer prints either '' or a sequence of quoted key-value pairs.

Answer (score -2):

```
[ -z ${!dict[*]} ] && echo "yes" || echo "no" yes
```

this should be fine to check it is empty.

Comment: This wold fail (produce an error) on any associative array with more than one key. It would report an array with only whitespace in its keys as empty.